# VMware Kernel-Headers

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules, vmware, linux-headers

I Installed VMware-Player-16.1.2-17966106.x86_64.bundle . When I ran it in the GUI it shows [image]

I use Arch Linux and I installed all required packages as per Arch wiki . Many answers for this kind of questions are Distribution Oriented (I tried didn't work). So please anyone with same problem resolved, post an answer.
Output of

```
pacman -Q linux 
linux 5.12.8.arch1-1
```

Output of

```
pacman -S linux-headers 


warning: linux-headers-5.12.9.arch1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) linux-headers-5.12.9.arch1-1

Total Installed Size:  129.25 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        0.00 MiB
```

Even I tried replacing original tarballs of VMware (vmmon.tar and vmnet.tar in /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/ ) with patched verson of https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/  github repository , As per Installation guide

```
When using a downloaded tarball, simply run

  tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
  tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only

to create the tarballs. In this case, there is no protection against
unwanted local changes.

Whatever way you used to create the tarballs, replace the original ones
provided by VMware

  /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar
  /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar

by patched versions. It is highly recommended to backup the original
tarballs before replacing them.

Once patched tarballs are installed, you can rebuild the modules as usual:

  vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

When I run  `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all`

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.

(process:1887): GLib-CRITICAL **: 08:21:25.344: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed
Failed to setup build environment.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure output of `pacman -Q linux linux-headers` match , If not perform a system upgrade using `pacman -Syu` so that kernel and kernel headers match. Refer to this https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance . After that  reboot the system. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Even if `linux` and `linux-headers` are at the same version, you need to make sure that you're actually running that kernel version (`uname -r` must match the version of `linux`). If you're not: reboot.